# Hibernate - Problem in parsing mapping file (.hbm.xml)

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I have an exception while running an Hibernate-based application. The exception is as follows:

```
16 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
16 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
16 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
31 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp     handling
94 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
94 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
219 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : app/data/City.hbm.xml
266 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(12) Attribute "coloumn" must be declared for element type "property".
266 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(13) Attribute "coloumn" must be declared for element type "property".
266 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(14) Attribute "coloumn" must be declared for element type "property".
```

It seems that it is not finding `coloumn` attribute of the `property` element in the mappings file but my mappings file do have the `coloumn` attribute.

Below is the mappings file (City.hbm.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="app.data">

  <class name="City" table="CITY">

    <id column="CITY_ID" name="cityId">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="cityDisplyaName" coloumn="CITY_DISPLAY_NAME" />
    <property coloumn="CITY_MEANINGFUL_NAME" name="cityMeaningFulName" />
    <property coloumn="CITY_URL" name="cityURL" />

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `column`. It's complaining because `coloumn` is not a valid attribute of `<property>`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. It must be **column** not **coloumn**.

Cheers!

Edit: too slow :)